# How do I add cssnano optimization rules in vue-cli 3?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, cssnano

I am trying to add cssnano optimization rules but with vue-cli, it doesn't seem to work. I added the following script in `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          require("cssnano")({
            preset: [
              "default",
              {
                discardComments: {
                  removeAll: true
                },
                mergeRules: true
              }
            ]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But it wouldn't work (see screenshot below)

*Screenshot - cssnano `mergeRules` didn't apply:*

[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 5):

You have to modify chainWebpack api to edit cssnano plugin options.

> Run these commands:
>
> ```
> npx vue-cli-service inspect --mode=production --plugins
> ```
>
> This gives you a list of plugins included in our webpack config. One
>   of them is called 'optimize-css'
>
> ```
> npx vue-cli-service inspect --mode=production --plugin optimize-css
> ```
>
> Now you get the config for that plugin, including the cssnano config.
>   You also get info in the comments about how to navigate to it through
>   webpack-chain.
>
> With that information, we can now use the chainWebpack api to edit the
>   plugin options:
>
> ```
> // vue.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   chainWebpack: config => {
>     config.plugin('optimize-css').tap(([options]) => {
>       options.cssnanoOptions.preset[1].svgo = false
>       return [options]
>     })
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Untested, so no guarantees :wink:

Source: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-cli-3-remove-svgo-from-cssnano-optimizations/53560/2